# Post a model from angularJS to WEBAPI

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, ionic-framework

It maybe a dumb question, but I can't get it right. I've searched all on stackoverflow questions, and google of course.

So, I got this class on my webapi

```
public partial class TaskList
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string task { get; set; }
}
```

Then my webapi controller

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] TaskList tasklistModel)
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, tasklistModel);
}
```

My angularJS controller

```
angular.module('ReminderDude.controllers', [])

.controller('HomeController', function($scope, dudeService) {
    $scope.CreateNewTask = function(tasklistModel){
        tasklistModel.id = '1';

        dudeService.store({
            data: JSON.stringify(tasklistModel)
        }).then(function(resp) {
            console.log(resp);
         },function(err) {
            console.error('Controller: Error', err);
        });
    }
})
```

My angularJS service

```
angular.module('ReminderDude.services', [])

.factory('dudeService', function($http) {
    var baseUrl = 'http://localhost:1142/api/values';
    return {
        store: function (tasklistModel){
            return $http({  
                        url: baseUrl,
                        method: 'POST',  
                        data: tasklistModel,  
                        headers: {  
                            "Content-Type": "application/json"  
                        }  
                    });
        }
    };
})
```

And lastly, the HTML

```
<ion-view view-title="Reminder Dude">
    <ion-content class="padding">
        <form ng-Submit="CreateNewTask(model)">
            <div class="list card">
                <div class="item item-divider">Hello! Please input your task below</div>
                <div class="item item-input">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="model.task" placeholder="Write Here" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <center>
                <button type="submit" class="button button-positive button-large">Save</button>
            </center>
        </form>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I made a breakpoint on my webapi controller, it hits but the model i passed on is null. Here's the returned data from my webapi controller:

```
Object {data: Object, status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}
config: Object    
data: Object       
headers: Object    
method: "POST"    
transformRequest: Array[1]
transformResponse : Array[1]
url : "http://localhost:1142/api/values"
__proto__ :
    Object: data
    Object:
        id: 0
        task: null
__proto__ :
    Object
    headers: function(name)
    status: 200
    statusText: "OK"
__proto__ :
    Object
```

Here's the list of what i've tried:

- use or remove the [FromBody] tag on my webapi controller
- use or remove JSON.stringify on my angularJS controller before sending my data to webapi controller
- change the "public HttpResponseMessage Post" to "public TaskList Post"
- console.log the data sent from my angularJS controller: {"task":"testTask","id":"1"}

Why it doesn't send correctly to my webapi?
Any answers and helps would be appreciated.

FYI: CORS is not a problem in my opinion, i've enabled it. Because if the CORS isn't enabled, it won't hit the breakpoint wouldn't it? If it's a CORS related problem, please correct me.

Thank you

UPDATE:

After a quite long discussion with @Mahesh Chand, i've successfully send the data to my webapi controller. here's what i've done:

change the angularjs controller to this:

```
angular.module('ReminderDude.controllers', [])

.controller('HomeController', function($scope, dudeService) {   
    $scope.CreateNewTask = function(tasklistModel){
        tasklistModel.id = 1;

        //before
        dudeService.store({
            data: tasklistModel
        }).then(function(resp) {
        console.log('response from api:'))
        console.log(resp);

        //after
        dudeService.store(tasklistModel).then(function(resp) {
            console.log('response from api:');
            console.log(resp);
            //ignore the console.log, it just my code to test the response from the api
```

Big thanks to @Mahesh Chand, thanks for noticing the 'data' that was unnecessary one. (that was a hell of dumb mistake)

Note for @Mahesh Chand: in my case, we really need the ng-model instead of ng-bind. if i use ng-bind, i won't get the value that i passed on from the view.

Hope this will help the others that have the same problem as me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FromBody] is used only when post request has form data but in your case you are submitting data in the request only. Thus, you've to remove [FromBody] in your Action of API controller

```
 [Route("save"), HttpPost]
 public HttpResponseMessage Post(TaskList tasklistModel)
```

Just for a good practice, use RoutePrefix attribute on Api Controller and Route attribute on Action as mentioned below:

```
 [RoutePrefix("api/my")]
 public class MyController : ApiController
 {
    [Route("save")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(TaskList tasklistModel)
    {
       //Your code here
    }
 }
```

Requests are serialized automatically. Thus, you have to remove Json.Stringify.
You should use id of model in controller as an integer not a character/string.

```
angular.module('ReminderDude.controllers', [])
.controller('HomeController', function($scope, dudeService) {
    //initialize the model here
    $scope.tasklistModel = {};
    //No need to pass it in parameter since it is directly accessible to View
    $scope.CreateNewTask = function(){
         $scope.tasklistModel.id = 1;

        dudeService.store($scope.tasklistModel).then(function(resp) {
            console.log(resp);
         },function(err) {
            console.error('Controller: Error', err);
        });
    }
})
```

Your Angular service also need one change. You should use post function avilable in $http as mentioned below:

```
angular.module('ReminderDude.services', [])

.factory('dudeService', function($http) {
    var baseUrl = 'http://localhost:1142/api/values';
    return {
        store: function (tasklistModel){
            //url will be baseUrl + api controller route prefix + action route
            console.log(tasklistModel)
            return $http.post(baseUrl+'api/my/save',tasklistModel);
        }
    };
})
```

Try ng-bind and your HTML would be

```
<ion-view view-title="Reminder Dude">
    <ion-content class="padding">
        <form ng-Submit="CreateNewTask()">
            <div class="list card">
                <div class="item item-divider">Hello! Please input your task below</div>
                <div class="item item-input">
                    <input type="text" ng-bind="tasklistModel.task" placeholder="Write Here" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <center>
                <button type="submit" class="button button-positive button-large">Save</button>
            </center>
        </form>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: hey thanks for answering, i've done the changes that you recommend. but it gives me an error 405 (Method Not Allowed) after adding [Route("save")] before the [HttpPost] attribute

Comment: @William I've updated my answer with some more changes in controller and HTML. One question, is your api controller action is getting invoked?

Comment: Full Url will be Domain name + RoutePrefix of controller + Route of action i.e. http://localhost:1142/api/my/save for my answer

Comment: what do you mean by invoked? if by giving the breakpoint and it hits when i call it, then yes.

Comment: is the parameter still null in the action of web api?

Comment: I've updated my HTML by using ng-bind and the angularJS controller. it gives me an error, tasklistmodel is not defined. i think it should be defined in the function parameter rather than using $scope.tasklistModel. and to answer your question, yes, it's still null on the parameter on the web api

Comment: tasklistModel should be used with ng-bind in HTML. I missed that. Sorry for that but it's updated now.

Comment: sorry, but it still gives me the same error on my angularJS controller: tasklistModel is not defined

Comment: $scope.tasklistModel should be used instead of just tasklistModel. I've updated that too.

Comment: thanks for keeping up with me. but sorry, it's still null on the parameter in the action of web api

Comment: You're welcome :) can you please put a break point at return $http.post(baseUrl+'api/my/save',tasklistModel); and check what's the value of tasklistModel?

Comment: here's the screenshot [link](http://oi68.tinypic.com/142smc3.jpg)

i'm afraid i can't put a breakpoint at my angular code. i use notepad++, but i have console.log the data. it contains the data that i want to send correctly.

Comment: Check console.log(tasklistModel) output before $http.post

Comment: oh okay sorry. it only got the id. tasklistModel.id = 1, but the tasklistModel.task is not there. i wonder, i have used the ng-bind as you told me

Comment: Sorry. I've noticed one more thing in your controller. You were creating one more object i.e. data from tasklistModel. No need to do that. Find the updated controller. This time it would work for sure

Comment: i've updated my question and marked your answer as the most helpful one. and i've summarize what i should be done from the start. thank you so much!